# Odoo - create_date field changes to bool type?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

I noticed one strange thing. I was creating compute method and I needed to use `create_date` field, but when I tried to `strptime`, I got error that I use `bool` field and I need to use string. When I printed it from method, it outputted as `False`. But when I gone into database and written sql query to get create_date, it showed me normal datetime.

The more interesting thing is, if I define `create_date` in view, then `create_date` becomes `str` type and I can see datetime when calling print. Does anyone know if its intended this way (and why) or it is some kind of bug?

Code that the produced these results:

```
from openerp import models, fields
from openerp.api import one, depends

class crm_lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    stage_deadline = fields.Datetime('Stage Deadline', compute="_compute_stage_deadline")


    @one
    @depends('section_id.stage_config_ids', 'stage_id', 'create_date')
    def _compute_stage_deadline(self):
        print type(self.create_date) #prints 'bool' if this field is not defined in view. Prints 'str'
        self.stage_deadline = datetime.now()
```

If I add this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>         
        <!-- CRM Lead Form View  -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_case_form_view_leads_inherit">
        <field name="name">CRM - Leads Form - Inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="priority" position="after">
                <field name="create_date" invisible="1"/>
            </field>
        </field>
        </record>        
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Then `create_date` becomes `str` type. If I delete this view, it goes back in `bool` type. So this way I can't use create_date if its not defined in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it has to do with unmet dependencies. First two dependencies where not used (`'section_id.stage_config_ids', 'stage_id'`) and it for some reason it evaluated `create_date` to `False` too. When I removed those dependencies, it was fixed.

The only thing that I don't understand is why including that field in view converted field back into `str` even though dependencies were wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the date field is present in the view, but is unfilled (empty) while saving, the functional field will get blank String while using that date in compute method, 
and if the date field isn't declared at all in the view it will evaluate to False.

Comment: But it changes its type instead of just evaluating to False. Also if I do not use new `api.depends`, then there is no such problem and I don't need to define it in view (because that field is only used behind the scenes).